How to use specific test occurrence records in dismo::maxent()
For the sake of reproducible results I have already randomly split my occurrence records into training and testing, and would like to input these records into dismo::maxent. I have attempted to do this using the code below:
\`mod_args
\[1\] "linear=TRUE"  
\[2\] "quadratic=TRUE"  
\[3\] "hinge=TRUE"  
\[4\] "product=TRUE"  
\[5\] "threshold=TRUE"  
\[6\] "betamultiplier=3"  
\[7\] "randomtestpoints=40"  
\[8\] "jackknife=TRUE"  
\[9\] "responsecurves=TRUE"  
\[10\] "testsamplesfile=C:/Users/Danielle/Downloads/presence_records_gridded_300.csv"

maxent_train <- dismo::maxent(env, # environmental variables (aka predictors) 
occ_train, # training occurrence records
bgr, # background points, n = 10000
args = mod_args,
removeDuplicates = FALSE)

However when doing this I get the following error message:
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcTd0O7/raster/maxent/1115481455/species.lambdas': No such file or directory

When I remove the argument testsamplesfiles=... from mod_args, the function works as expected.
Is there a way to supply maxent with specific testing occurrence records?
